# How to concatenate one column by the same id with rest of the columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

I want to add tags by id in each column and I don't know what to add to the function in order for that to work. How to apply group by on it?

For example, if I get this data:

| id_text | id_word | word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 | hello |
| 1 | 345 | world |
| 2 | 23 | dog |
| 2 | 56 | cat |

I'll get:

| id_text | id_word | word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 456,345 | hello/world |
| 2 | 23,56 | dog/cat |

Here's my code:

```py
def columns(text_id,word_id,word):
    with open('.....csv','a', newline='\n') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        l=[]
        for i in range(len(text_id)):
            if i==i-1:
             l.append(text_id,word_id)
             print(l)
             l.append(word+"|")
             print(l, end=" ")
             i+=1
        writer.writerow(l)
        print(' ')

#print(df)
for j in range(len(df)):
    #print('==========================================================================')
    text_id=df["id"][j]
    word_id=df["word_id"][j]
    word=df["word"][j]
        columns(text_id,word_id,word)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note: the general verb used to describe this process is 'merge' or 'group'.

Comment: Use `df.groupby("id_text", as_index=False).agg({"id_word": lambda d: ",".join(d.astype(str)), "word": "/".join})`.